# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object. Check the render method of

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I have this snippet in my React Native login screen,

```
<View style = {{ marginTop: 20 }} >
   <Text styles = {{ fontSize: 15 }}>Forgot Password? · First time here?</Text>
</View>
```

Everything works fine.

---

But, just then... when I make a tweak,

```
<View style = {{ marginTop: 20 }} >
  <Text styles = {{ fontSize: 15 }}>Forgot Password? · First time here?</Text>
  <Touchable styles = { styles.link } onPress = { () => { this.props.navigation.navigate('RegisterScreen') } } ><Text>Sign up</Text></Touchable>
</View>
```

**This happens**:
[image: Wierd error]

---

Please help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: What is Touchable? Is it a component of your own or did you mean to use TouchableOpacity?

Comment: Yea. I figured out that it has to be TouchableOpacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Touchable` is not a valid element type.
If you want to use a `Touchable` element on your project you can use [`TouchableOpacity`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity), [`TouchableHighlight`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight), [`TouchableNativeFeedback`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback) (Android only) or [`TouchableWithoutFeedback`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback).